# Is there any alternative for pd.notna ( pandas 0.24.2). It is not working in pandas 0.20.1?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

"Code was developed in pandas=0.24.2, and I need to make the code work in pandas=0.20.1. What is the alternative for pd.notna as it is not working in pandas version 0.20.1.

```
df.loc[pd.notna(df["column_name"])].query(....).drop(....)
```

I need an alternative to pd.notna to fit in this line of code to work in pandas=0.20.1

Comment: Have you tried `df.loc[~pd.isna(df["column_name"])]`?

Comment: `df["column_name"]).notnull()` cc @NilsWerner

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO
from io import StringIO
cmd = 'NSLOOKUP email.fullcontact.com'
df = pd.DataFrame()
a = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
b = StringIO(a.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8'))
df = pd.read_csv(b, sep=",")
column = list(df.columns)
name = list(df.iloc[1])[0].strip('Name:').strip()
name
```